# Firebase error: "Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module './clone.js'"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, clone, firebase-storage

When I run `firebase deploy --only functions` I get this error message:

```
Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module './clone.js'
```

Here's my code, copied from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/Bucket#upload):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const bucketName = 'myapp.appspot.com';
const filename = './hola_mundo.wav';

admin.initializeApp();

exports.Storage = functions.firestore.document('Test_Value').onUpdate((change, context) => {

  storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
    gzip: true,
    metadata: {
      cacheControl: 'no-cache'
    }
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketname}`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });

});
```

Is `clone.js` this [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the constants into the function and the error went away:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.Storage = functions.firestore.document('Test_Value').onUpdate((change, context) => {

  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
  const storage = new Storage();
  const bucketName = 'myapp.appspot.com';
  const filename = './hola_mundo.wav';

  storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
    gzip: true,
    metadata: {
      cacheControl: 'no-cache'
    }
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketname}`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });

});
```